# Is there a way in VBA to add custom text in an email when you copy the contents from a word file

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

So I have a macro (in Excel) that takes the email address from an Excel cell, copies the content of a word file (while maintaining the formatting because it's something I need), takes the email address to send it to from an excel cell and adds attachments.

I try to add, let's say "Dear *name*" to the start but this is where I run into issues.

Here is the code I currently use

```
Sub ThanksEmailFromDoc()
    Dim wd As Object, editor As Object
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim oMailItem As Object, oOLapp As Object
    Dim Sender As String 
    Dim AttachmentA As String
    Dim AttachmentB As String
    Dim Template As String

    Sender = "send@test.com" 

    Template = "C:\Files\Template.docx"
    AttachmentA = "C:\Files\AttachmentA.pdf"
    AttachmentB = "C:\Files\AttachmentB.pdf"
    
    Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application") 
    Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(Filename:=Template, ReadOnly:=True) 
    doc.Content.Copy 
    doc.Close 
    Set wd = Nothing
    
    Set oOLapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
    Set oMailItem = oOLapp.CreateItem(0) 
    With oMailItem 
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = Sender 
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 
        Set editor = .GetInspector.WordEditor 
        editor.Content.Paste 
        .To = Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row).Value 
        .Subject = "Thanks for your interest" 
        .Attachments.Add (AttachmentA) 
        .Attachments.Add (AttachmentB) 
        .Display 
    End With

    Set oOLapp = Nothing
    Set oMailItem = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

What I've tried so far, and failed is to add the following code before the editor.content.paste

```
    .HTMLBody = "Dear" & Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row)
```

I expected it to add this before pasting the contents of the word file, but instead it didn't even show up.

Comment: try `editor.Paragraphs.Add.Range.Text = "my text" : editor.Paragraphs.Add.Range.Paste`

Comment: Where exactly would I have to put this?

Comment: Replacement for  `editor.Content.Paste`

Comment: Thank you! I tried it, but only the pasted text from the word document shows up. The "my text" part gets overwritten. Still appreciate the help lots!

Comment: i dont see in your code the part of .HTMLBody